# PHP form script error, unexpected ")"

Tags: php, post

I'm new to PHP, so i dont know a whole lot about it.

I created a script, with some help from a tutorial, but every time i run it on my website it creates an error.

Unexpected ")" in row 19. I've tried searching for an answer, but haven't found any solution.

The script looks like this:
http://pastebin.com/0ANLFQTr

Comment: I don't see a problem in the script. Are you sure it's line 19 of this script? Please post the full error text and tell us what this script is called.  It's also recommended on StackOverflow to paste your code, not link to it.

Comment: Agreed. No error in this script. Just no declaration of $errName and $errEmail (missing).

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there.  With a reference to the original tutorial.

Comment: @u_mulder I've already read that one, but didnt find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

That code which you show is fine.

Try it:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $from = 'Servicemodul Kontaktform';
    $to = 'mat.joe@outlook.dk';
    $subject = 'Besked fra Servicemodul Kontaktform';
    $errName = false;
    $errEmail = false;

    $body = "From: $name\n E-mail: $email\n";

    if (!isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $errName = "Udfyld venligst med dit navn";
    }

    if (!isset($_POST['email']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Angiv venligst en gyldig E-mail';
    }
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail) {
        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-success"> Tak, vi sender dig en mail snarest</div>';
        } else {
            $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Der var et problem da vi skulle sende din mail, prøv igen senere</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: it seems to work as i dont get the error message anymore, thanks!

Comment: @rad11 did you make any change from the original code?

Comment: Yes, add isset functions and set $errName and $errEmail default values. Did something happen? The author wrote above that now everything works

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    if  (isset($_POST["submit"])){
$name   =   $_POST['name'];
$email  =   $_POST['email'];
$from   =   'Servicemodul Kontaktform';
$to     =   'mat.joe@outlook.dk';
$subject    =   'Besked fra Servicemodul Kontaktform';

$body   =   "From: $name\n E-mail: $email\n";

if  (!$_POST['name']){
    $errName    =   "Udfyld venligst med dit navn";
}

if  (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))   {
$errEmail   =   'Angiv venligst en gyldig E-mail';
}

if (!isset($errName) && !isset($errEmail)) {
    if  (mail   ($to,    $subject,    $body,   $from))  {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success"> Tak, vi sender dig en mail snarest</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Der var et problem da vi skulle sende din mail, prøv igen senere</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```